# JsonFx - parsing double to int

Tags: c#, parsing, casting, jsonfx

Given the following simple class I'm trying to deserialize with `JsonFx`:

```
public class JsonFxTest
{
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
    public JsonFxTest()
    {
    }
}
```

Note: I'm calling an API which I'm not the owner of, so I can't change what is given back!

Simplified, the following string is given back:

> "{\"IntValue\" : \"20.00\"}"

which I want to deserialize using `JsonReader.Deserialize<JsonFxTest>("{\"IntValue\" : \"20.00\"}")`.

The error thrown is:

> 20.00 is not a valid value for Int32.

which is totally fine and correct.

Question is, how can I parse it into an integer without using regex or something like this on the string received?